# link not loading properly in android N webview

Tags: android, webview

I want open this link (http://e-sign-poc.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/) like mobile browser using webview

```
mWebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wb_sample);
WebSettings webSettings = mWebview.getSettings(); webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
mWebview.loadUrl("http://e-sign-poc.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/");
```

This link not loading properly in webview, but this link works perfectly in telegram webview

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "link not loading properly" ?

Comment: I think if your page contains some plugin then you have to enable plugins.

`if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 8) {
        webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    } else {
        webview.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    }`

Comment: @RujulGandhi already tried this, but not working :(

Comment: @GingerNinja23 Here i'm trying to load a web page that contains signature input view, but it's not loading properly i'm not able to sign the document.

Comment: Have you enable `android:hardwareAccelerated=true` in mainfest ?@Ranjithkumar

Comment: @RujulGandhi yeah its enabled already.

Comment: okay so now what you are getting wrong ? @Ranjithkumar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141629/discussion-between-ranjithkumar-and-rujul-gandhi).

Answer (score 0):

**Wait for some time after you load URL to WebView**

***It will work perfectly in my device***

or

**Try with this code**

```
 url = "http://e-sign-poc.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/" +
            "";
    linearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: yes It's working in older version, but it's not working in android N

Answer (score 0):

Try with it -

```
 webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvTest);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);


        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webSettings.setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onLoadResource(view, url);
                progressBar.setProgress(view.getProgress());
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.example.com");
```